# Integral of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I don't understand why integral of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is : 
$1/2(x\times\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sinh^{-1}(x))$ and how can I calculate it with no help of computer ? tnx a lot

Comment: It should be actually $\sin^{-1}$

Comment: @iamvegan - how about x = sinh u?  as a substitution

Comment: @iamvegan  - sorry it is, you are right

Comment: i think the one shown is for sqrt(1 + x^2)

Comment: One interesting observation...if you bound the limit to $-1$ to $+1$ then the integral gives $\frac{\pi}{2}$....(graph is a semicircle)....

Comment: It is the area enclosed by an arc of a unit circle, the $x$-axis and two vertical lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x = \sin u, \quad dx = \cos u \; du$

$\displaystyle\int \sqrt{1 - x^2} \; dx$

$= \displaystyle\int\cos u \sqrt {1 - \sin ^2u} \; du$

$= \displaystyle\int\cos ^2 u \; du$

$= \displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac {\cos 2 u}{2} \; du$

$= \dfrac{u}{2} +  \dfrac{\sin 2u}{4}$

$= \dfrac{u}{2} + \dfrac{2\sin u \cos u}{4}$

$=\dfrac { \arcsin(x) }{2} + \dfrac {x\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{2} + c$

Comment: Can you tex it please?

Comment: @ iamvegan can never get it to work, it just comes out as codes on my firefox browser

Comment: @ iamvegan - actually I know how to use it now, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Multiply $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ by $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Another way: make the substitution $x=\cos(t)$.