# $\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\tan\alpha)(\tan\beta)}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta} d\alpha d\beta=(0.9999999913...)(\pi/2)$? Seriously?

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals, expected-value, conjectures

In the diagram, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are independent uniformly random real numbers in $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

[image]

> What is $\mathbb{E}(h)$?

Superimposing a cartesian coordinate system, the equations of the lines are $y=(\tan\alpha)x$ and $y=(-\tan\beta)(x-1)$, so the $y$-coordinate of their intersection is $\frac{(\tan\alpha)(\tan\beta)}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}$. So we have

$$\mathbb{E}(h)=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\tan\alpha)(\tan\beta)}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta} d\alpha d\beta$$

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uutvlip2qj?lang=zh-CN) says $I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\tan\alpha)(\tan\beta)}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta} d\alpha d\beta$ is $(0.9999999913...)(\frac{\pi}{2})$. Is that a computer error, and the result is exactly $\frac{\pi}{2}$? I don't know how to evaluate the integral. Wolfram evaluates the [inside integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29tanA%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29tanB%5C%2841%29%2CtanA%2BtanB%5D%2CA%5D) but doesn't evaluate [both integrals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BIntegrate%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29tanA%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29tanB%5C%2841%29%2CtanA%2BtanB%5D%2CA%5D%2CB%5D).

If Desmos is not very reliable, then maybe my earlier [weird conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4804630/398708) is actually true.

(This question was inspired by a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4811456/398708) about random points in a square.)

**Edit**: In the comments, @G.Gare notes that Mathematica says the integral $I$ is exactly $\pi/2$. Can we prove it? Maybe an intuitive geometrical argument?

**Edit2:** I seek to generalize this result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4812776/398708).

Comment: Is there a way to control the number of decimal places Desmos works with? Could you ask it to use 50 decimal places?

Comment: Mathematica says it's $\pi/2$, but the indefinite integral is a mess

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't know.

Comment: @G.Gare Thanks. I would very grateful if you could use Mathematica to check the linked conjecture: $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\int_{k}^{k+1}\left(\frac{\sin (\pi x)}{x}\right)^2\mathrm dx\right)\overset{?}{=}\pi/2$

Comment: It's not giving a result for this one

Comment: @G.Gare What about the product of the first $10^{50}$ terms for example?

Comment: @Dan It seems you are interested in making conjectures, I would recommend register for Wolfram Cloud if possible, it's free. Someone on the site made the same suggestion to me. Also generally speaking Desmos loses a lot of precision while dealing with Double Integrals.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: For the product of the first whatever terms you can use any programming language...

Comment: It may help or not, but the integrand is equal to $\dfrac{\sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$

Comment: @MartinR I did the same calculation and tried on Mathematica, which now gives results faster

Comment: I  have the explict formula for the integrals between $0$ and $t \leq \frac \pi 2$.

Comment: With $(u,v)=\left(\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}, \frac{1-\tan y}{1+\tan y}\right)$ we get another integral identity for $\pi$,$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\frac{1-u}{1+u^2}\,\frac{1-v}{1+v^2}\,\frac{du\,dv}{1-uv}=\pi$$Mathematica can compute this exactly, even over each quadrant.

Comment: I’m surprised nobody cited this video by Grant Sanderson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851U557j6HE&t=0s or the related problem. It seems it is not your case, but sometimes what looks like a computer error in approximating integrals is actually true!

Comment: It is rather easy to believe that a computer algebra calculation of an integral whose true value is exactly $\pi/2$ would result in a numeric approximation with "only" 9 digits of accuracy. So, yes. Seriously.

Comment: You wrote "Desmos is not very reliable" but I think you meant "Desmos is extremely reliable and has an impressive precision of $10^{-8}$ on this integral" ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\tan\alpha)(\tan\beta)}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta} d\alpha d\beta\overset{\binom{\alpha=\arctan x}{\beta=\arctan y}}{=}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{xy}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(x+y)}dxdy$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+y^2}\right)\frac{xy}{x+y}\frac{dxdy}{y^2-x^2}$$
$$=2\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^2}\frac{xy}{x+y}\frac{dxdy}{y^2-x^2}\overset{x=ty}{=}2\int_0^\infty dy\int_0^\infty\frac{t\,dt}{(1+t^2y^2)(1-t)(1+t)^2}$$
$$=2\int_0^\infty\frac{t\,dt}{(1-t)(1+t)^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{1+t^2y^2}$$
$$=\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(1-t)(1+t)^2}\overset{x=\frac1t}{=}-\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{x\,dx}{(1-x)(1+x)^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,2I=\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,I=\frac\pi2$$

Comment: Can you comment on the singularity at $t=1$?  I see you have sort of canceled it out in the penultimate step but how can you justify carrying it around?

Comment: @Ron Gordon, thank you for your question. Regarding the singularity: we are allowed to write the integral as
$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+y^2}\right)\frac{xy}{x+y}\frac{dxdy}{y^2-x^2}$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^2}\frac{xy}{x+y}\frac{dxdy}{y^2-x^2}-\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+y^2}\frac{xy}{x+y}\frac{dxdy}{y^2-x^2}$$
where every integral exists separately and is evaluated in the principal value sense.
The last integral can be evaluated directly (also in the principal value sense) and gives
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(1-t)(1+t)^2}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 17):

A variant of [Svyatoslav's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4812190/42969), using polar coordinates $(x, y) = (r \cos \phi, r \sin\phi)$:

$$
\begin{align}
I &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan\alpha \tan\beta}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta} d\alpha d\beta \\
 &=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{xy}{(x+y)(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}dxdy \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos\phi \sin\phi}{\cos \phi + \sin\phi}\left( 
\int_0^\infty \frac{r^2}{(1+r^2 \cos^2\phi)(1+r^2\sin^2\phi)} \, dr
\right) d\phi \, .
\end{align}
$$
For $ 0 < \phi < \pi/2$ the inner integral is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{ \sin^2 \phi-\cos^2\phi } \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{1}{1+r^2 \cos^2 \phi)} - \frac{1}{1+r^2 \sin^2\phi}\right) dr \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{ \sin^2 \phi-\cos^2\phi } \left[ \frac{\arctan(r \cos\phi)}{\cos \phi} - \frac{\arctan(r \sin\phi)}{\sin\phi}\right]_{r=0}^{r=\infty} \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{\cos \phi \sin\phi (\cos\phi + \sin\phi)} \frac{\pi}{2} \, .
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$
 I = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(\cos\phi + \sin\phi)^2} d\phi
=  \frac{\pi}{2}  \left[ \frac{\sin \phi}{\cos\phi+\sin\phi}\right]_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\pi/2}= \frac{\pi}{2}  \, .
$$

Answer (score 6):

*Long comment*

Related result: The expected length of one of the sides of the triangle (not the base) is

$$\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin (\alpha+\beta)}d\alpha d{\beta}$$

$$=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[(\sin \beta)\log\left(\tan\left({\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}\right)\right)\right]_0^{\pi/2}d\beta$$

$$=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin \beta)\log\left(\frac{\tan\left({\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+\beta}{2}}\right)}{\tan\left({\frac{\beta}{2}}\right)}\right)d\beta$$

$$=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\left[\beta-\log\left(\frac{\sin b}{2}\right)-(\cos\beta)\log \left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\left(\cot\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)+1\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)}\right)\right]_0^{\pi/2}$$

$$=\frac{2\pi+\log 16}{\pi^2}$$

(with help from Wolfram)

Answer (score 4):

The first antiderivative is quite simple.

After solving the inner integral, we are left with:

$$\int \sin (b) \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  \cos (b)+\sin (b) \,\log (\tan   (b))\right)\,db$$ Now, there is a quite nasty antiderivative.

Using the bounds, the first term is $\frac \pi 4$.

So, for the  total,
$$I=\frac \pi 4+ \frac{1}{16} (4+i \pi ) \pi-i\frac{ \pi ^2}{16}=\frac \pi 2$$

**Edit**

$$I=\int \frac{\tan (a) \tan (b)}{\tan (a)+\tan (b)}\, da$$ $$I=\sin (b) (a \cos (b)-\sin (b) \log (\sin (a+b)))$$ Using the bounds, the integral written at the top.

$$J=\int \sin ^2(b) \log (\tan (b))\,db$$
$$J=\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i b}\right)-\frac{1}{8} i
   \text{Li}_2\left(e^{4 i b}\right)+\frac{b}{2}+b \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(e^{2 i b}\right)+$$ $$\frac{1}{2} b \log (\tan
   (b))-\frac{1}{4} \sin (2 b) \log (\tan (b))$$

Now, use the bounds.

Comment: "The required antiderivatives are quite simple....A nasty antiderivative." Is it simple, or is it nasty? It can't be both, can it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Thnaks for pointing ! The first one is simple.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)+ \tan(\beta)}= -\cot(\alpha+ \beta) +\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)+ \tan(\beta)}$$

$$\displaystyle I:=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int _0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)+ \tan(\beta)} d \alpha d \beta=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int _0^{\frac{\pi}2}-\cot(\alpha+ \beta) +\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)+ \tan(\beta)} d \alpha d \beta$$

$\\[4pt]$

for $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\tan x+ c}dx$ let $\tan x = t $ then $$\int \frac{1}{\tan x+ c}dx= \int \frac{1}{(t^2+1)(t+c)}dt$$ $$=\frac{c}{c^2+1}\int\frac{1}{1+t^2} dt -\frac{1}{2(c^2+1)}\int \frac{2t}{t^2+1}dt + \frac{1}{c^2+1}\int\frac{1}{c+t} dt $$
$$\frac{c}{c^2+1} \arctan(t) - \frac{1}{2(c^2+1)}\ln|t^2+1| +\frac{1}{c^2+1} \ln|t+c|$$
$$=\frac{c}{c^2+1} x +\frac{1}{(c^2+1)}\ln|\cos(x)| +\frac{1}{c^2+1} \ln|\tan(x)+c|$$
$\\[3pt]$
$$I=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}2} \biggr|-\ln|\sin(\alpha + \beta)| + \frac{\tan(\beta)}{\sec^2(\beta)} \alpha +\frac{1}{(\sec^2(\beta))}\ln|\cos(\alpha)| +\frac{1}{\sec^2(\beta)} \ln|\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)|\biggr|_0 ^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d\beta$$
$$=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}2} \ln|\tan(x)| +\frac{\pi}{4}\sin(2\beta )+ \cos^2(\beta )(-\ln(\tan(\beta))) d\beta$$

first we can see that $\displaystyle \int _0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\tan(\alpha)) d\alpha= \int _{0}^ \frac{\pi}{2} \ln ( \cot \alpha)du =0 $ because $\displaystyle \int _0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\tan(\alpha)) d\alpha =-\int _0 ^ \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\tan(\alpha)) d\alpha$ by king's rule

and $\displaystyle  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(2\beta) d \beta =-\frac{\cos(2\beta)}{2} \biggr|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = 1$ so that means
$$I = \frac{\pi}{4} - \int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\beta)\ln(\tan(\beta)) d\beta$$

$$J:=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\beta)\ln(\tan(\beta)) d\beta=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\beta)\ln(\sin(\beta)) d\beta-\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\beta)\ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta  $$

$$=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\beta)\ln(\sin(\beta)) d\beta+\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos(\beta)) (1-\cos^2(\beta)) d\beta -\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta $$

since $\displaystyle \int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\beta)\ln(\sin(\beta)) d\beta=\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos(\beta)) (\sin^2(\beta)) d\beta$ by king's rule so

$$J = 2\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(\beta)\ln(\sin(\beta)) d\beta-\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta $$

let $\displaystyle y= \sin(\beta)$

$$=2\int _0^{1}\ln(y)\sqrt{1-y^2}dy     -\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta $$
here I will use integration by parts and integrate [$\sqrt{1-y^2} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1909752/1132763)
$$J=y \ln(y)\sqrt{1-y^2} +\arcsin(y)\ln(y)\biggr|_0^1 -\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y^2} dy - \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin{y}}{y} dy      -\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta $$

since $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{y \to 0}y \ln (y) =0$(why ? use L'Hôpital's rule) and $\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\arcsin{y} \ln (y) =0$(why ? substitute $\sin(t) = x$ and use L'Hôpital's rule )

and since $\displaystyle \int _0 ^1 \sqrt{1-y^2}  dy = \frac{\pi}{4}$

$$J= -\frac{\pi}{4 } + \int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin{y}}{y} dy      -\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta  $$
$$-\frac{\pi}{4 } -\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \beta \cot(\beta) d\beta       -\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta  $$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{4 } -  \beta \ln(\sin ( \beta))\biggr|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} +\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta  -\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos(\beta)) d\beta  $$

$$= -\frac{\pi}{4 }$$

so $$\color{red}{I = \frac{\pi}{4} -J =\frac{\pi }{2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on an earlier comment: let $(u,v)=\left(\dfrac{1-\tan \alpha}{1+\tan \alpha}, \dfrac{1-\tan \beta}{1+\tan \beta}\right)$, i.e. $(\alpha,\beta) = \left(\dfrac\pi4-\arctan u,\dfrac\pi4-\arctan v\right)$, to rewrite the integral as

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\tan \alpha \tan \beta}{\tan \alpha + \tan\beta} \, d\alpha\,d\beta \\
&= \frac12 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\frac{1-u}{1+u} \cdot \frac{1-v}{1+v}}{\frac{1-u}{1+u} + \frac{1-v}{1+v}} \, \frac{du}{1+u^2} \, \frac{dv}{1+v^2} \\
&= \frac12 \underbrace{\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1-u}{1+u^2} \, \frac{1-v}{1+v^2} \, \frac{du\,dv}{1-uv}}_{=\pi}
\end{align*}$$

The inner integral is elementary:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1-u}{1+u^2} \, \frac{du}{1-uv} \\
&= \frac{1+v}{1+v^2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{1+u^2} + \frac{1-v}{1+v^2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{u}{1+u^2} \, du - \frac{v(1-v)}{1+v^2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{1-uv} \\
&= \frac\pi2 \frac{1+v}{1+v^2} - 2 \frac{1-v}{1+v^2} \operatorname{artanh}v
\end{align*}$$

and we're left with

$$\begin{align*}
& \frac\pi2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1-v^2}{\left(1+v^2\right)^2} \, dv - 2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-v)^2}{\left(1+v^2\right)^2} \operatorname{artanh} v \, dv \\
&= \frac\pi2 + \underbrace{\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-v)^2}{\left(1+v^2\right)^2} \log \frac{1-v}{1+v} \, dv}_{=:J}
\end{align*}$$

Showing $J=\dfrac\pi2$ can be done by enforcing $v\mapsto\dfrac{1-v}{1+v}$, folding up the subsequent integral at $v=1$ and expanding into partial fractions, exploiting power series, and integrating by parts:

$$\begin{align*}
J &= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\left(1-\frac{1-v}{1+v}\right)^2}{\left(1+\frac{(1-v)^2}{(1+v)^2}\right)^2} \log v \, \frac{dv}{(1+v)^2} \\
&= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{v^2}{\left(1+v^2\right)^2} \log v \, dv \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \left(\frac1{1+v^2} - \frac2{\left(1+v^2\right)^2}\right) \log v \, dv \\
&= 2 \sum_{n\ge0} (-1)^{n+1} (2n+1) \int_0^1 v^{2n} \log v \, dv \\
&= 2 \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} = 2\arctan 1 = \frac\pi2
\end{align*}$$